# Multi-list with search showing gibberish after switching to SOLR Cloud

Tags: content-editor, solr

I'm running Sitecore 8.1 (Original Release), and last night we switched our SOLR indexes to use a dedicated SOLR Cloud set of servers instead of using a stand-alone SOLR instance on our CM server. Everything seemed to be working fine last night when we made the switch.

However, our Content Editors reported to us this morning that things were not working very well. We started investigating the issue and we found that 1 of our `Multi-list with Search` fields looked like this:

[image: Garbled Multi-list with search field]

This only happens on a few (but not all) of our `Multi-list with Search` fields. We see the same behavior on any template that is based on the template(s) that are having the issue. The garbage displayed here seems to be the `GUIDs` of the items that were selected prior to this field not displaying properly.

Here's my questions:

1. Could this have anything to do with moving my indexes to SOLR Cloud?
2. Where do I start looking to figure out how to fix this problem?

Comment: any sitecore logs entries ?

Comment: No, there aren't any clues in the Sitecore logs. Good idea, though!

Comment: To troubleshoot the I would suggest comparing request/response from the browser developer tools and if nothing clear from there then sniff the HTTP communication between Solr and Sitecore using Fiddler to understand where things are different with this template and other templates.

Comment: I've tried FIddler (with the help of Sitecore Support), and it didn't really show anything either :( I've got an open ticket with Sitecore Support, and will be posting the answer when/if I get one.